# How can I cause an InfoPath Form Web Part to load a previously filled form?

Tags: 2010, infopath

I have an InfoPath 2010 Web Part that receives a value from a data connection. I want to use this value to load a form with data filled in from a previous submit. How can I do this? The form submits to a library and its properties are populated as fields on the form.

UPDATE...
On my page I have a drop down list in one web part. This is connected to an InfoPath Form Web Part, providing the selected value into my InfoPath form. I need the InfoPath form to look in a Form Library for an existing form that has this value in a field. If it finds a match, it should load this form. Hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: for what purpose? You could always have it displayed in a form webpart.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Please explain a bit more. What is the bigger picture?